# How approve backstopjs ref images in GitHub Actions?

Tags: github-actions, backstop.js

I'm using [BackstopJS](https://github.com/garris/BackstopJS) for regression tests and trying to implement GitHub workflow.

#### At first little introduction how BackstopJS works:

1. We have reference images (pictures) of browser pages
2. We run BackstopJS test and compare actual browser view and reference image
3. Check backstop report HTML page in browser and decide which is correct actual view or reference image
4. If browser view is an updated correct version, we run `backstop approve` command to rewrite reference image with new actual image

#### What can be implemented inside GitHub actions:

1. Download reference images from S3 bucket
2. Run BackstopJS test
3. Save HTML report and actual browser images as artifacts
4. Download HTML report stored as artifact and check if new version of images is correct
5. ??? Here is a problem

#### Problem:

Workflow is already ended, and we don't able to `approve` new images. So, is here any way to add dialog inside Pull Request if `test` Action failed to be able upload new images (stored as artifacts) to S3 as new reference images? Or some way to retry failed test with new parameters (let's say it will be env `AUTO_APPROVE=true`) to be able re-run test with new images approvement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I implemented interactive workflow:

```yaml
---
name: 'BackstopJS test'

on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - edited
      - opened
      - synchronize
    branches:
      - 'develop'

env:
  AWS_ACCOUNT_ID: '12345678'
  AWS_REGION: 'us-east-1'
  AWS_BUCKET_NAME: 'bucket_name'
  AWS_BUCKET_PATH: 'bucket_folder'
  AWS_BUCKET_KEY: 'bitmaps_archive.zip'

defaults:
  run:
    shell: bash
    working-directory: backstop_test

jobs:
  test:
    # yamllint disable rule:line-length
    if: ${{ (github.event.action != 'edited' ) || contains(github.event.pull_request.body, 'approve ') }}
    name: 'BackstopJS test'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      id-token: write
      contents: read
      pull-requests: read
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Get last commit message (only 100 commits in PR are acceptable)
        if: ${{ github.event.action != 'edited' }}
        env:
          COMMITS_URL: ${{ github.event.pull_request.commits_url }}
        run: |
          if [ "${COMMITS_URL}x" != "x" ]; then
            echo "COMMIT_MSG=$(curl -H "Authorization: token ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" "${COMMITS_URL}?per_page=100" | jq -r .[-1].commit.message)" >> "${GITHUB_ENV}"
          else
            echo '::warning ::Cannot get commits list URL'
            echo 'COMMIT_MSG=' >> "${GITHUB_ENV}"
          fi

      - name: Search for approve directives in PR body or commit message
        shell: python
        env:
          PR_MSG: ${{ github.event.pull_request.body }}
        run: |
          from os import environ as env
          from sys import exit

          file_path = env.get('GITHUB_ENV', None)
          if file_path is None:
            raise OSError('Environ file not found')

          autoapprove = False
          approve_only = False
          commit_message = env.get('COMMIT_MSG', '')
          pr_message = env.get('PR_MSG', '')

          with open(file_path, 'a') as gh_envs:
            if '[cancel test]' in commit_message.lower() or '[skip test]' in commit_message.lower():
              gh_envs.write('SKIP_TEST=1\n')
              print("::warning ::Test is skipped by commit tag")
              exit(0)
            elif 'cancel test' in pr_message.lower() or 'skip test' in pr_message.lower():
              gh_envs.write('SKIP_TEST=1\n')
              print("::warning ::Test is skipped by tag in PR message")
              exit(0)
            else:
              gh_envs.write('SKIP_TEST=0\n')

          if '[approve me]' in commit_message.lower():
            autoapprove = True
            approve_only = True
            print("Reference bitmaps will be approved by commit message")
          else:
            print("Last commit message:", commit_message)
            if '${{ github.event.action }}' == 'edited':
              approve_only = True
            pr_message = pr_message.split('\n')
            last_commit_id = '${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}'
            commit_id = None
            for line in pr_message:
              if line.startswith('approve '):
                commit_id = line.split(' ')[-1].rstrip('\n\r')
                break

            if commit_id:
              if last_commit_id.startswith(commit_id):
                autoapprove = True
              else:
                print(
                  "::warning ::approved commit sha and last commit sha are missmatched:",
                  commit_id,
                  "/",
                  last_commit_id
                )
            else:
              print("Auto approvment disabled")

          with open(file_path, 'a') as gh_envs:
            if autoapprove:
              gh_envs.write('AUTOAPPROVE=1\n')
            else:
              gh_envs.write('AUTOAPPROVE=0\n')
            if approve_only and autoapprove:
              gh_envs.write('APPROVE_ONLY=1\n')
            else:
              gh_envs.write('APPROVE_ONLY=0\n')

      - name: Configure AWS credentials
        if: ${{ env.SKIP_TEST != 1 }}
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          role-to-assume: arn:aws:iam::${{ env.AWS_ACCOUNT_ID }}:role/github-iam-role
          aws-region: ${{ env.AWS_REGION }}
          role-session-name: backstopjs_test_runner

      - name: Download and extract reference bitmaps
        if: ${{ env.SKIP_TEST != 1 }}
        run: |
          aws s3 cp "s3://${AWS_BUCKET_NAME}/${AWS_BUCKET_PATH}/${AWS_BUCKET_KEY}" "./backup_${AWS_BUCKET_KEY}" && unzip -od ./backstop_data "backup_${AWS_BUCKET_KEY}" || echo "::warning file=${AWS_BUCKET_KEY}::No reference bitmaps archive found"

      - name: Run tests
        if: ${{ env.SKIP_TEST != 1 }}
        run: |
          if [ "${AUTOAPPROVE}" == "1" ] || [ "${AUTOAPPROVE^^}" == "TRUE" ] || [ "${AUTOAPPROVE^^}" == "YES" ]; then
            echo "**Autoapprove is activated. Reference images will be renewed**   " >> "${GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY}"
          else
            {
              echo "**Autoapprove is not active. Current reference images will be used**   ";
              echo "";
              echo "Add \`approve ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}\` line to PR description";
              echo "and test JOB will be automatically re-run to approve new reference bitmaps";
              echo "";
              echo "＊ if you will do new commit into PR, \`sha\` of current approvment should be updated too   ";
              echo "";
              echo "Also \`[approve me]\` tag may be added inside commit message to renew bitmaps automatically   ";
            } >> "${GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY}"
          fi
          {
            echo "";
            echo "Test may be cancelled by using \`[skip test]\` (or \`[cancel test]\`) tag inside commit message   ";
            echo "or by using \`skip test\` (or \`cancel test\`) code word inside PR message   ";
            echo "";
            echo "---";
          } >> "${GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY}"
          # Run tests here.
          # If AUTOAPPROVE=1 then backstop test → backstop approve → backstop test will be run (both reports will be saved)
          # If AUTOAPPROVE=1 and APPROVE_ONLY=1 then backstop reference → backstop test will be run
          # ...
          # Set Job to fail or success depends on tests exit status code
          # In this example tests are not included, and status will be always failed if autoapprove is 0
          if [ "${AUTOAPPROVE}x" == "1x" ]; then
            echo "IS_FAILED=0" >> "${GITHUB_ENV}"
          else
            echo "IS_FAILED=1" >> "${GITHUB_ENV}"
            echo "Error: test \`BLAHBLAHBLAH\` failed with status code: \`1\`" >> "${GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY}"
          fi

      - name: Upload new reference ritmaps to S3 bucket
        if: ${{ env.AUTOAPPROVE == 1 && env.IS_FAILED == 0 && env.SKIP_TEST != 1 }}
        run: |
          cd backstop_data && zip -ur "../${AWS_BUCKET_KEY}" bitmaps_reference && cd .. && \
          aws s3 cp "${AWS_BUCKET_KEY}" "s3://${AWS_BUCKET_NAME}/${AWS_BUCKET_PATH}/${AWS_BUCKET_KEY}"
          if [ -f "backup_${AWS_BUCKET_KEY}" ]; then
            aws s3 cp "backup_${AWS_BUCKET_KEY}" "s3://${AWS_BUCKET_NAME}/${AWS_BUCKET_PATH}/backup_${AWS_BUCKET_KEY}"
          fi

      - name: Save HTML reports
        if: ${{ env.SKIP_TEST != 1 }}
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: html_reports
          path: backstop_test/report

      - name: Save logs (only if failed)
        if: ${{ env.IS_FAILED == 1 && env.SKIP_TEST != 1 }}
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: test_logs
          path: backstop_test/logs

      - name: Set to fail
        if: ${{ env.IS_FAILED == 1 && env.SKIP_TEST != 1 }}
        uses: actions/github-script@v3
        with:
          script: |
              core.setFailed('Some of regression tests failed. Check Summary for detailed info')
```

- Flow runs on:

  - PR contents updates (`updated`)
  - New commits inside PR (`synchronize`)
  - New PR created (`opened`)
- If PRs body has line `skip test` (`cancel test`) or commits message has tag `[skip test]` (`[cancel test]`), then test will be skipped
- If PRs body has line `approve commit-SHA` (where `commit-SHA` is a sha of a last commit in PR) or commits message has tag `[approve me]`, then new reference bitmaps will be created

  - If `approve` line is present in PR, only one test with new reference images will be run
  - If `approve` tag is present in commit message, two tests will be run (before and after approvement) and two reports will be saved
- Reference images are uploaded/downloaded/stored from/to/in S3 bucket